# How to recover from a RAID 1 Disk Failure on HP Proliant Gen8 v2

Tags: hp-proliant, raid1

I just had a disk failure on one of my physical drives of a RAID 1 logical drives, on a HP Proliant Gen8 v2 Server running Windows 2012 R2.

The problem is that the original drive is 500GB and I only was able to find a 1TB replacement. When I insert this new drive and reboot, the OS doesn't start.

I can see the alerts on HP's Smart Storage Administrator software, but I cannot remove the failed drive from the array without loosing all the data (the software clearly warns of data loss).

Now I am in a situation where I am running on a single physical disk and can't recover my RAID 1 configuration. I considered buying another 1TB drive, but I am not sure how will I move my data from the current 500GB drive.

Is there a way to rebuild my RAID 1 using this 1TB drive AND the 500GB drive? If I buy another 1TB drive, how will I move my data e rebuild a RAID 1?

Comment: Is this software RAID (in Windows) or hardware RAID (from the server)? There's any number of things it could be in either case, but you'll need the logs from one place or the other. Either way though, a reboot should not be necessary - just pop in the new disk and the rebuild should either start automatically, or be able to be kicked off (depending on how the RAID was built)

Comment: My basic guess is that when the new disk is inserted, but unconfigured, server is trying to boot off your new, blank disk. So once you've done a disk replacement (the specifics of which I'm not super familiar with on HPs) it should be all good.

Comment: According to the [user guide, page 47](https://community.hpe.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/itrc-264/148204/3/HP%20Smart%20Storage%20Administrator%20User%20Guide.pdf) you want to "Heal" the array. There are no further details so I don't know what the UI looks like or if it lets you choose the replacement disk.